# How to get subclass member in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

For example I have two class

class A:

```
class A
{
   private:
   int a;

}
```

subclass B:

```
class B: private A
{
   private:
   char b;

   public:
   char getB();
}
```

code:

```
int main()
{
   A* item = new B();
   char b = (B)item->getB();
}
```

Should I use cast or should I redesign program if I need to do something like that? I dont want to use polymorphism.

Comment: Are you looking for virtual functions? Also I think you meant to write `((B*)item)->getB();`.

Comment: I dont want to use virtual functions.

Comment: Then why are you using base class pointer for your `B*`?

Comment: Because I need this. I use polimorphism in other case. I need only get `char b` in one case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problems**

1) B privately inherits from A.  So only a B can cast a `B*` to an `A*`.

2) The priorities of your expression are same as `(B)(item->getB());` So this will not compile as `item` is an `A` and A has no member `getB()`.

3) It's better to use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` instead of the old C style cast.

**The solution**

1) Use public inheritance if you want to cast between your derived class and base class outside of the classes themselves.

2) Then use parenthesis:

```
char b = ((B*)item)->getB();
```

3) Or prefer more precise form:

```
char b = static_cast<B*>(item)->getB();
```

4) But when you're doing an **downcast** like this, it's at your own risk. If the `A*` pointer points to something else than a B or a class derived from B, then it's undefined behaviour.

As you consider having a polymorphic use of your type, you'd better have a virtual destructor so that you can delete item with the appropriate destructor (here it would use A's destructor instead of B's).

As soon as you've at least one virtual function, you can use the safer dynamic_cast:

```
 if(dynamic_cast<B*>(item)) {  // would be nullptr if item doesn't point to a B object
     char b = dynamic_cast<B*>(item)->getB();
     ... // further processing of the char
  }
  else cout << "Ooops!"<<endl;
```

Comment: s/upcasting/downcasting/

Comment: Is other way with no risk? I dont want pure virtual function because I had to define this function to all subclass A. I dont want virtual function because I had to defined it in class A.

Comment: @user3191398 yes but with at least one virtual function.  See edit in point 4

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dynamic_cast` that safely converts pointers and references to classes up, down, and sideways along the inheritance hierarchy (cppreference.com):

```
dynamic_cast<B*>(item)->getB();
```

, instead of old style C cast:

```
((B*)item)->getB();
```

**Edit:**

You should use public inheritance to use `dynamic_cast`. For what purpose `private` inheritance was used? In your example it doesn't make much sense IMHO. Also using inheritance without virtual destructor is dangerous.

Comment: But it won't convert from a private base.